The problem with the movement and behavior of the ghost indicator when dragging items in PySide6
I am working on an application on PySide 6, which implements the function of dragging elements to change their order. In the program, the user can create elements (such as TextElement, HeaderElement, ImageElement) that consist of a header and a basic structure. These items can be dragged and rearranged in the list.
The program uses a ghost indicator, which visualizes the place where the element will be moved during dragging. The indicator resizes to match the size of the dragged element, which allows the user to see where the element will be inserted.
The elements in the program have different sizes, which depend on their contents. For example, an element with an image may be larger in height than an element with text. The problem occurs when dragging an element through other elements of different sizes.
When I drag an element and move the mouse past elements of a larger or smaller size, the ghost indicator begins to "jump", not understanding exactly where it needs to be displayed. Sometimes the ghost doesn't stay in the right position or shifts to the side. Moreover, when an element is released, it does not always end up where the ghost was displayed, which causes problems with the correct placement.

![It can be seen that when moving the ghost element with the mouse cursor, the ghost hesitates and changes its position, trying to determine the correct place to insert between other elements.]
Here is part of the code from my DragWidget class, which is responsible for determining the location of the ghost, it worked properly as long as the elements were the same size:
def _find_drop_location(self, e):
        pos = e.position()  # Get the cursor position
        spacing = self.blayout.spacing() / 2  # Half of the spacing between items

        for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
            w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()  # Get each item

            # Check for vertical orientation:
            drop_here = (
                pos.y() >= w.y() - spacing
                and pos.y() <= w.y() + w.size().height() + spacing
            )

            if drop_here:
                break

        return n  # Return the index of the position

And here is the full code for the context:
from PySide6.QtCore import QMimeData, Qt, Signal
from PySide6.QtGui import QDrag, QPixmap, QAction, QKeySequence
from PySide6.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication,
    QHBoxLayout,
    QLabel,
    QMainWindow,
    QVBoxLayout,
    QWidget,
    QPushButton,
    QLineEdit,
    QScrollArea,
    QGroupBox, 
    QFileDialog,
    QTextEdit,
    QListWidget, QListWidgetItem
)
from manager import DataManager
from elements import *
import os

class Ghost(QLabel):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setContentsMargins(25, 5, 25, 5)
        self.setStyleSheet(
            "QLabel { background-color: #ccc; border: 1px solid black; }"
        )

        # Setting style: light blue color with 50% transparency and dashed border
        self.setStyleSheet("""
            QLabel {
                background-color: rgba(0, 99, 192, 0.2);  /* Light blue background with 50% transparency */
                border-radius: 5px;  /* Rounded corners */
            }
        """)

        # Setting the initial size of the ghost element (same as draggable items)
        self.setFixedSize(400, 200)  # Width: 400px, Height: 200px

class DragWidget(QWidget):
    """
    This widget allows adding items and changing their order by dragging.
    """

    orderChanged = Signal(list)

    def __init__(self, *args, orientation=Qt.Orientation.Vertical, **kwargs):
        super().__init__()
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

        # Setting orientation (vertical or horizontal) for proper item arrangement.
        self.orientation = orientation

        if self.orientation == Qt.Orientation.Vertical:
            self.blayout = QVBoxLayout()  # Use QVBoxLayout for vertical orientation
            self.blayout.setSpacing(15)  # Fixed spacing between items (e.g., 15 pixels)
        else:
            self.blayout = QHBoxLayout()

        # Adding the ghost indicator that will appear during dragging
        self._drag_target_indicator = Ghost()
        self.blayout.addWidget(self._drag_target_indicator)
        self._drag_target_indicator.hide()

        self.setLayout(self.blayout)

        # Add a stretch at the bottom to make items stick to the top
        self.blayout.addStretch()

    def dragEnterEvent(self, e):
        e.accept()

    def dragLeaveEvent(self, e):
        self._drag_target_indicator.hide()
        e.accept()

    def dragMoveEvent(self, e):
        # When moving an item, find where to place it
        index = self._find_drop_location(e)
        if index is not None:
            self.blayout.insertWidget(index, self._drag_target_indicator)
            e.source().hide()
            self._drag_target_indicator.show()
        e.accept()

    def dropEvent(self, e):
        widget = e.source()  # Get the dragged item
        self._drag_target_indicator.hide()  # Hide the indicator
        index = self.blayout.indexOf(self._drag_target_indicator)
        if index is not None:
            self.blayout.insertWidget(index, widget)  # Insert the item at the new location
            self.orderChanged.emit(self.get_item_data())  # Emit signal to update order
            widget.show()
            self.blayout.activate()
        e.accept()

    def _find_drop_location(self, e):
        pos = e.position()  # Get the cursor position
        spacing = self.blayout.spacing() / 2  # Half of the spacing between items

        for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
            w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()  # Get each item

            # Check for vertical orientation:
            drop_here = (
                pos.y() >= w.y() - spacing
                and pos.y() <= w.y() + w.size().height() + spacing
            )

            if drop_here:
                break

        return n  # Return the index of the position

    def add_item(self, item):
        # Add a new item to the layout before the stretch
        self.blayout.insertWidget(self.blayout.count() - 1, item)

    def get_item_data(self):
        # Collect data from all items (to check the order)
        data = []
        for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
            w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()
            if w != self._drag_target_indicator and w is not None:
                data.append(w.id)
        return data

class EditWindow(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, is_new_project=False, project_path=None):
        super().__init__()

        # Create DataManager object
        self.data_manager = DataManager()
        self.project_name = ""

        self.drag = DragWidget(orientation=Qt.Orientation.Vertical)

        # If it's a new project, call new_project()
        if is_new_project and project_path:
            self.project_name = self.data_manager.new_project(project_path)
            if self.project_name:
                self.setWindowTitle(f"{self.project_name}")
            else:
                self.setWindowTitle("Error creating project")
        elif project_path:
            self.project_name = os.path.basename(project_path)
            self.setWindowTitle(f"{self.project_name}")

            # Load the existing project and add its elements to the interface
            elements = self.data_manager.open_project(project_path)
            for element in elements:
                self.add_new_item(element_type=element["type"], content=element["content"], element_id=element["id"])
        else:
            self.setWindowTitle("Unknown project")

        # Set minimum window size
        self.setMinimumSize(800, 600)

        # Main container
        main_container = QWidget()
        main_layout = QHBoxLayout(main_container)

        # Main content
        content_container = QWidget()
        content_layout = QVBoxLayout(content_container)

        # Project name edit field
        self.project_name_edit = QLineEdit(self.project_name)
        self.project_name_edit.editingFinished.connect(self.rename_project)
        content_layout.addWidget(self.project_name_edit)

        # Create scrollable main widget
        self.scroll_area = QScrollArea(self)
        self.scroll_area.setWidgetResizable(True)

        # Create a draggable widget and add it to the scroll area
        scroll_content = QWidget()
        scroll_layout = QVBoxLayout(scroll_content)
        scroll_layout.addWidget(self.drag)
        self.scroll_area.setWidget(scroll_content)
        content_layout.addWidget(self.scroll_area)

        # Add content container to the main layout
        main_layout.addWidget(content_container)

        # Sidebar
        sidebar = QWidget()
        sidebar.setFixedWidth(300)
        sidebar_layout = QVBoxLayout(sidebar)
        
        # Create an element list for the sidebar
        self.element_list = QListWidget()
        sidebar_layout.addWidget(self.element_list)

        # Add elements to the list
        element_types = [
            {"type": "text", "icon": "icons/text.svg", "name": "Text"},
            {"type": "header", "icon": "icons/header.svg", "name": "Header"},
            {"type": "image", "icon": "icons/image.svg", "name": "Image"}
        ]
        
        for element in element_types:
            item = QListWidgetItem()
            item_widget = QWidget()
            item_layout = QHBoxLayout(item_widget)
            
            # Add icon and name
            icon_label = QLabel()
            icon_label.setPixmap(QPixmap(element["icon"]).scaled(24, 24, Qt.KeepAspectRatio, Qt.SmoothTransformation))
            item_layout.addWidget(icon_label)
            
            name_label = QLabel(element["name"])
            item_layout.addWidget(name_label)
            
            # "Add" button
            add_button = QPushButton("Add")
            add_button.clicked.connect(lambda _, e=element["type"]: self.add_new_item(element_type=e))
            item_layout.addWidget(add_button)
            
            item_widget.setLayout(item_layout)
            item.setSizeHint(item_widget.sizeHint())
            self.element_list.addItem(item)
            self.element_list.setItemWidget(item, item_widget)

        # Continue existing code
        main_layout.addWidget(sidebar)

        main_container.setLayout(main_layout)
        self.setCentralWidget(main_container)

        # Connect signal to update order in JSON when the order changes
        self.drag.orderChanged.connect(self.update_order_in_json)

        # Set up the menu
        self.create_menu()

    def create_menu(self):
        """Creates a menu with File, Edit, View, Help items."""
        menubar = self.menuBar()

        # File menu
        file_menu = menubar.addMenu("File")
        
        # Export action
        export_action = QAction("Export to Word", self)
        export_action.setShortcut(QKeySequence("Ctrl+E"))
        export_action.triggered.connect(self.export)
        file_menu.addAction(export_action)

    def rename_project(self): 
        """Method to rename the project through DataManager."""
        new_project_name = self.project_name_edit.text().strip()
        if new_project_name and new_project_name != self.project_name:
            success = self.data_manager.rename_project(new_project_name)
            if success:
                self.project_name = new_project_name
                self.setWindowTitle(new_project_name)
            else:
                print(f"Failed to rename project to {new_project_name}")

    def add_new_item(self, element_type="text", content=None, element_id=None):
        """Adds a new item to the interface and JSON."""
        # Generate a unique ID and create empty content if a new item is being created
        if element_id is None:
            content = content or {}  # Empty dictionary if content is not provided
            element_id = self.data_manager.add_element(element_type, content)

        # Create corresponding object depending on the type of item
        if element_type == "text":
            new_element = TextElement(content=content, id=element_id, data_manager=self.data_manager)
        elif element_type == "header":
            new_element = HeaderElement(content=content, id=element_id, data_manager=self.data_manager)
        elif element_type == "image":
            new_element = ImageElement(content=content, id=element_id, data_manager=self.data_manager)
        else:
            print(f"Unknown element type: {element_type}")
            return

        # Add the item to the interface and pass it to DragWidget
        self.drag.add_item(new_element)
        print("New item added")

    def update_order_in_json(self, new_order):
        """Updates the item order in JSON through DataManager."""
        self.data_manager.order_elements(new_order)  # Update JSON file with new order

    def export(self):
        """Opens a dialog to select a directory and calls export_project."""
        directory = QFileDialog.getExistingDirectory(self, "Select directory to save")
        if directory:
            self.data_manager.export_project(directory)

What have I already tried
def _find_drop_location(self, e):
    pos = e.position()  # Get the cursor position
    spacing = self.blayout.spacing() / 2  # Half the spacing between elements

    closest_index = None
    min_distance = float('inf')  # Minimum distance

    for n in range(self.blayout.count()):
        w = self.blayout.itemAt(n).widget()  # Get each widget

        if w is not None and w != self._drag_target_indicator:
            # Check the distance between the center of the element and the cursor position
            element_center = w.y() + (w.size().height() / 2)
            distance = abs(pos.y() - element_center)

            if distance < min_distance:
                min_distance = distance
                closest_index = n

            # Check for vertical orientation:
            drop_here = (
                pos.y() >= w.y() - spacing
                and pos.y() <= w.y() + w.size().height() + spacing
            )

            if drop_here:
                closest_index = n
                break

    return closest_index  # Return the index of the position


Please edit your post and provide a proper [mre], right now your code is too long (it contains lots of irrelevant code) and is not reproducible (it requires imported classes that we know nothing about). We must be able to easily copy, paste and run your code without substantial changes.
